# 2 or more buttons which have both the same function. How?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 buttons (but actually I want to have more buttons). I want both of them to open the same modal-pop up. Is this somehow possible? Maybe I have to use some kind of id?

SO:
Step 1: Press button 1 -> opens modal & u can close it again

Step 2: Press button 2 -> opens the same modal & u can close it again

The modal button will have an input field, a select field and a button which adds the inserted information into a table. I already have this function but I didn't included them in the code. I only wanted to show you necessary code:)

You are welcome to test the code, to understand what I want:)

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    const trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
    const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close");

    function toggleModal() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }

    function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            toggleModal();
        }
    }

    trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: scale(1.1);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
    }
    .modal-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: white;
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        width: 24rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }
    .close-button {
        float: right;
        width: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .close-button:hover {
        background-color: darkgray;
    }
    .show-modal {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        transform: scale(1.0);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
    }
```

```html
<table id="table" border="2" class="fruitTable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Apple
    <button class="trigger">Click here to trigger the modal!</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table" border="2" class="mitarbeiterTabelle">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Banana
        <button class="trigger">Click here to trigger the modal!</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>


  <div id="myModal" class="modal">  
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
I want to eat a lot. This modal will have more functions later (like an Input field and a button...)
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a collection of matching elements (.trigger) and add the same event listener to all of them :

```
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    const triggers = document.querySelectorAll(".trigger");
    const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close");

    function toggleModal() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }

    function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            toggleModal();
        }
    }
    triggers.forEach(function (x){  
       x.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    });
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

Comment: Thank you, its perfect!  But now I have noticed, that my modal isn't working like I want it to:/ Dammit haha. But your solution is working, thanks:)